# How to separate frameticks from the vertical axis?

Tags: plotting, style, ticks, frame

I'm trying to separate frame ticks from the vertical axes and so far I've found a solution to that end by adding the following command inside the "Plot" main command

```
FrameTicks -> {{{{0.2, "0.2 "}, {0.4, "0.4 "}, {0.6, "0.6 "}, {0.8, 
     "0.8 "}, {1, "1.0 "}, {1.2, "1.2 "}}, None}, {Automatic, None}}
```

Notice that there is a space after calling the tick's label i.e.  "0.1_". My question is: How can I separate frame ticks from the vertical axes automatically, with out specifying all ticks and its labels?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Kindly present a **minimal working example**; i.e., enough Mathematica code to replicate your problem. The code should be in copy-paste-able form so that respondents can experiment with it. The code snippet you have included so far does not evaluate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, 
       Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 17, FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ 
     Range[0, 1.2, 0.2], None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

> [image: oneway]

More examples for illustrative purposes

```
Table[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, 
        Framed[#, FrameMargins -> position, FrameStyle -> None]} & /@ 
      Range[0, 1.2, 0.2], None}, {Automatic, None}}], {position, 0, 
  21}]
```

> [image: two]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @JasonPeña you're very welcome. Glad I was able to help. Thanks for the accept!